# System.Web.Mvc.Web desaparecido, o que posso fazer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Depois de algumas atualizações, meus helpers começaram a dar problemas, exemplo, se eu fosse usar o `@Html.TexBoxFor`, o Razor não reconheceria.

Depois de pesquisar muito, fui indicado usar o `@using System.Web.Mvc.Web` na View que eu estava escrevendo. Ai veio a surpresa: Meu `System.Web.Mvc` não possui o `Web`.

A algum tempo funcionava normalmente, não sei o que pode ter acontecido e estou iniciando em MVC agora.

Comment: Você pode incluir na sua pergunta os dois `web.config`, o da raiz e o de dentro do diretório `Views`?

Comment: Quais atualizações ??? e qual versão se ta usando ?

Answer (score 1):

*Se você tiver com problemas em relação a isso, pode ser que deva voltar as configurações originais.*

**Como?**

Nesse [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc), temos o endereço que explica corretamente como deve proceder em uma atualização/retorno do MVC no Visual Studio. Existe nesse link várias versões tudo depende de saber qual versão estava sendo utilizada.

**Exemplo:**

Para utilizar [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console), faça assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na frente `PM>` cole a respectiva versão que você está usando, por exemplo:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.0
```

e pressione `<Enter>`